# How can I render different views for items in a list in Aurelia?

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I am currently building a dashboard with Aurelia and am very new to this framework. In the dashboard I want to have different types of dashlets in a list.

How can I do that? Do I have to include a switch in the embedding view do decide which view to render? If so how can I do this?

Any pointers are appreciated! :)

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be worth using `<compose>`. Say your main dashboard component is pulling in other components like so:

**dashboard.html**

```
<template>
  <Component-A />
  <Component-B />
  <Component-C />
  <Component-D />
</template>
```

Instead of explicitly listing out these components, we could rewrite this using `<compose>` along with an array of metadata:

**dashboard.html**

```
<template>
  <div repeat.for=”component in components”>
    <compose view-model=”${component.viewModel}” />
  </div>
</template>
```

**Array of components**

```
export const components = [
    {viewModel:  ‘component-a.js’ },
    {viewModel:  ‘component-b.js’ },
    {viewModel:  ‘component-c.js’ },
    {viewModel:  ‘component-d.js’ }
];
```

That's the general idea behind `<compose>`: dynamic view generation. However here are some additional resources:

- http://www.sitepoint.com/composition-aurelia-report-builder/
- http://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/10/aurelia-dynamic-composition/